# Transfer data from .csv files to a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to code a Macro in Excel that:

1. Goes through hundreds of `.csv` files.
2. Get their names and put them in the first row of the target workbook.
3. Copy `columns E & R` from each `.csv` file and paste them below their corresponding name in the target workbook.

**Example:** in the target workbook, I should get, the title_1 (of csv_1) in cell A1, then data from `columns E & R` of `csv_1`  pasted in `cells A2 & B2`. Column C empty. Then title_2 (of csv_2) in `cell D1`, respective `columns E & R` pasted in `D2 & E2`. Column F empty and so on...

[I would like the data to be organize like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5TLl.png)

Attempt:

```
Sub LoopExcels ()
    
    Dim directory As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim ColOutputTarget As Long
    
    ColOutputTarget = 1
    
    Set wsTarget = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    
    directory = "C:\data"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
    
    Do Until fileName = ""
        
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        
        j = j + 1
        i = 1
        Cells(i, 1) = fileName
        
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets        'my excels contain only one sheet but didn't know how to get rid of the "For each sheet"
            wsTarget.Cells(i, j).Value = sheet.Name
            j = j + 2
            
        Next sheet
        
        With wsTarget
            .Range("A" & ColOutputTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("E1:E100").Value        'Need to copy all data in columns it can be 10 cells and it doesn't exceed 100 cells
            .Range("B" & ColOutputTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("R1:R100").Value
            
            ColOutputTarget = ColOutputTarget + 1
            
        End With
        
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        fileName = Dir()
        
    Loop
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
    
End Sub
```

I've been looking for a solution with no luck.

- I found a way to loop through files
- I managed partially to get the names of each file (I found a code that goes thru all sheets in an Excel file. My files contain only one sheet so maybe it can be simplified)
  And for some reason it doesn't copy the full name. some files have LONG names +50 characters.
- I am having issues with copy/pasting the columns. Each column has data from 10 to 100 cells.
  The code below, go thru the files but paste the data in the same column. I end up getting only the data from the last excel file it opens which get pasted in the first 2 columns.
  I can't find a way to make it shift to the next column every time its done with each csv file.

Comment: I can't understand... When you say "3 cells distance between each name" distance in the x axis or in the y axis? ... Then.. you say "copy two columns from the each excels below their corresponding names" ..What?¿?.. I suggest you improve your explanation..

Comment: @Gass, I would like to leave empty column between each group. Ideally there will be the title1 in cell A1, then data from two columns starting from cells A2 & B2. Column 3 (C) empty. Then title 2 in cell D1, respective columns in D2 & E2. Column F empty and so on...

Comment: Ok. I got you. Could you please try to simplify your main post as clearly and brief as possible? Probably then I will be able to help you.

Comment: @Gass, Thanks for you comment. I'll do it

Comment: I still don't understand why you write `copy two columns from each excel (E & R) below their corresponding names.` What do you mean?? Please clarify this in the main post. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Much better....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For order to work:

- you need to place the Excel file (that has the macro) inside the folder of the `.CSV` files.
- create 2 sheets in the main Excel file with the names "file names" and "target sheet". You can change this in the code if you want.
- if you are using Windows just insert the path of the folder containing the .csv files.
- if you are using mac insert the path of the folder containing the `.csv` files and change all the `"\"` in the macro to `"/"`.

  ```
  Sub Awesome()

  getNames
  positionTitles
  transferData

  End Sub

  Sub getNames()

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim counter As Long

    counter = 1

    'Specify folder Path for the .csv files
    sFilePath = "c:\"

    'Check for back slash
    If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
    End If

    sFileName = Dir(sFilePath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        If Right(sFileName, 3) = "csv" Then
            'Display file name in immediate window
             Sheets("file names").Cells(counter, 1) = sFileName
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        'Set the fileName to the next available file
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop

  End Sub


  Sub positionTitles()

  Dim counter As Long
  Dim used_range As Range
  Dim col As Long

  col = 1

  Set used_range = Sheets("file names").UsedRange

  For counter = 1 To used_range.Rows.Count

  Sheets("target sheet").Cells(1, col) = Sheets("file names").Cells(counter, 1)

  col = col + 4

  Next counter

  End Sub


  Sub transferData()

  'turn off unnecessary applications
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim file_name As String
  Dim counter As Long
  Dim used_range As Range
  Dim main_wb As Workbook
  Dim col As Long
  Dim key As Boolean
  Dim last_row As Long
  Dim second_key As Boolean

  col = 1

  Set main_wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set used_range = Sheets("file names").UsedRange


  For counter = 1 To used_range.Rows.Count

    file_name = main_wb.Sheets("file names").Cells(counter, 1)

    Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & file_name, Local:=True

    'transfer data to target_sheet
    For col = col To 1000

        If key = False Then
            last_row = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E" & last_row).Copy
            main_wb.Sheets("target sheet").Cells(2, col).PasteSpecial
            key = True
        ElseIf second_key = False Then
         last_row = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("R1:R" & last_row).Copy
        main_wb.Sheets("target sheet").Cells(2, col).PasteSpecial
        second_key = True
     Else
        last_row = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K" & last_row).Copy
        main_wb.Sheets("target sheet").Cells(2, col).PasteSpecial
        col = col + 2
        Exit For
    End If

    Next col

    key = False
    second_key = False
    Workbooks(file_name).Close savechanges:=False

  Next counter

  'turn on applications
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you Gass, this answers perfectly my question . Just wondering,  if I want to copy and paste an additional third column from these excels, (for instance column K, in addition to E & R). Is it possible to just duplicate the code in the "transfer data to target_sheet" section? (I tired it it didn't work).

Comment: You are welcome bro. It is not that easy. Give me some time, I'll try to code it for you.

Comment: Okay Ayon, try it. If it works I would appreciate if you could vote up the answer. It gives me reputation points.